# What precisely is a scala evidence parameter

Tags: scala

I've been trying to find an authoritative definition of what is an evidence parameter, to no avail, for solving a case of "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type....". Can you please provide a very good explanation for what an evidence parameter exactly is?

Comment: this is a good short post: http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-implicits-and-typeclasses-in-scala

Comment: Great one @corn_dog. That post really nails it. Just thinking... could we not have used structural types for the same end.

Comment: No, not at all because the way in which one `Foo`s an Integer may not be the same as the way one `Foo`s a `java.sql.Timestamp` so you can't rely on a particular method shape.

Comment: By the way -- the [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499663/what-precisely-is-a-scala-evidence-parameter#comment56741760_34499663) references [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20171001150154/http://www.cakesolutions.net:80/teamblogs/demystifying-implicits-and-typeclasses-in-scala) which has since been removed although nearly every resource about the subject points to it!

Answer (score 18):

I'll try posting my own answer, improving it later as it goes. Let us start with a motivational scenario, but you can jump to the TLDR below then come back here as needed.

In one scenario, evidence parameters can be seen as a means of enriching a class with some behavior (method/s) from outside its original definition.

A mild rehash of the great post at [Cake Solutions](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-implicits-and-typeclasses-in-scala):

In case you have not already intuitively written such code before, here's a code demonstration of evidence parameters in use.

```
object EvidenceExample {

  // class with no methods
  case class Bar(value: String)

  // a trait the class Bar had not implemented
  trait WithFoo[A] {
    def foo(x: A): String
  }

  // object that attaches an implementation of the trait for Bar - for methods
  // willing to play along with this kind of trait attachment - see immediately below
  implicit object MakeItFoo extends WithFoo[Bar] {
    def foo(x: Bar) = x.value
  }

  // method willing to recognize anything as having trait WithFoo, 
  // as long as it has evidence that it does - the evidence being the previous object
  def callFoo[A](thing: A)(implicit evidence: WithFoo[A]) = evidence.foo(thing)
  
  callFoo(Bar("hi")) // and it works
}
```

You might read that code from the bottom up to realize that a class `Bar` has been enriched outside its original definition. Yet ― only functions that play along with the evidence ceremony can see it as enriched.

There's very little magic going on in this pattern ― although this is a unique language feature ― the wrapper object associates the trait to `Bar`, and `callFoo` relies on that association.

We could even write the same pattern without implicits, but then the last line, the one that calls the method, would need an extra parameter ― the economics of whether to use an implicit or not ― are entirely up to you.

You can up-sugar or down-sugar it as you wish, for example here's a minor syntax improvement:

(only the last `def` herein modified, and the comments removed now)

```
object EquivalentEvidenceExample {

  case class Bar(value: String)

  // a trait the class Bar had not implemented
  trait WithFoo[A] {
    def foo(x: A): String
  }
  
  implicit object MakeItFoo extends WithFoo[Bar] {
    def foo(x: Bar) = x.value
  }
  
  def callFoo[A:WithFoo](thing: A) = implicitly[WithFoo[A]].foo(thing) // lightly sugared syntax, frankly only more confusing
  
  callFoo(Bar("hi"))
}
```

And there's nothing requiring of you to name anything with the string `evidence`. The compiler just knows this is an evidence parameter by the way it is used in all these equivalent cases.

More generally or etymologically, [borrowing from the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500934/1509695), an evidence parameter is one that "evidences" a specific property of a type, and it is required by the compiler wherever a method's signature manifests such a requirement (in the other answer, there is no evidence supplied for type `Any` being `<:< Foo`, as required by the method's signature, hence it is a case of a missing evidence).

*Failure* to the have an evidence object available as an implicit, will result in the famous `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type ...` because the compiler knows this is part of an evidence pattern and not just a missing implicit (as much as this difference matters to you).

#### TLDR:

Succinctly speaking, an evidence parameter for some class `S` is a parameter of a type `T[S]` (so, a parameter that is a class) that defines one or more things about `S` ― thus "evidencing" something about `S` ― that makes `S` eligible for extended usage by a caller, beyond the original definition of `S`. The exact shape such a `T[S]` should have, is exemplified in my borrowed examples above, by `implicit object MakeItFoo`.

Answer (score 7):

The language specification uses the term "evidence" in [§7.4 Context Bounds and View Bounds](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html):

> A type parameter `A` of a method or non-trait class may also have one or more context bounds `A : T`. In this case the type parameter may be instantiated to any type `S` for which *evidence* exists at the instantiation point that `S` satisfies the bound `T`. Such evidence consists of an implicit value with type `T[S]`.

With this syntactic sugar you get synthetic parameters which the spec calls "evidence parameters". (Note that this also covers view-bounds `<%` which are now deprecated).

Since often explicitly written implicit parameters are also named `evidence`, I think it's valid to call any implicit parameter an "evidence" if it witnesses a specific property of a type.
Take for example [`<:< [A, B]`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5adc400f5ece336f3f5ff19691204975d41e652e/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L377-L389) that evidences that `A` is a sub-type of `B`:

```
trait Foo

trait Bar[A] {
  def baz(implicit evidence: A <:< Foo): Unit
}
```

Then if you try this:

```
trait Test {
  def bar: Bar[Any]

  bar.baz
}
```

This fails with a compilation error:

```
<console>:58: error: Cannot prove that Any <:< Foo.
         bar.baz
             ^
```

The exact wording can be specified with the [`implicitNotFound` annotation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.annotation.implicitNotFound). Without a specific code example, it's unclear what generates the "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type....".

Here's an example of a custom message:

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Oh noes! No type class for ${A}")
trait MyTypeClass[A]

trait Bar[A] {
  def baz(implicit evidence: MyTypeClass[A]): Unit
}
```

Then:

```
trait Test {
  def bar: Bar[Any]

  bar.baz
}
```

Fails with the custom message:

```
<console>:58: error: Oh noes! No type class for Any
         bar.baz
             ^
```

Comment: Is it really just a convention and not baked into the language? compiler errors using that term rather than mirroring the argument name, and having it mentioned in the [language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) I could go through further persuasion towards that..

Comment: Thanks @matt - I wasn't aware that this word was used in the spec. I have elaborated on that now.

Comment: Admittedly I sometimes find it a little confusing how this is different from regular implicit conversions and the enriching pattern. A good blog post might well tie them all together in a more cohesive manner (and I'd say being so economical on reusing existing language tokens for these language features could be a topic of debate, at least consistent with the underscore philosophy).

Comment: Some differences are that, even if eventually some kind of conversion is used, you can use it as a constraint far away from where the actual conversion is applied.  Also you don't actually need to do some actual conversion.  See eg http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2010/06/implicit-tricks-type-class-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Scala evidence parameters are prepended to implicit parameter list.

```
def foo[A: M](implicit b: B): C
// expands to:
// def foo[A](implicit evidence$1: M[A], b: B): C
```

See specifications for more details.
https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html