# scala pass a variable list of parameters and types to a function

Tags: scala, function, generics, type-parameter

How can I pass a variable list of parameters and types to a function?
I.e. the depicted approach which is using pattern matching seems a bit clumsy.
In an `trait` the function `foo` is defined. However in concrete implementations a different subtype (with additional fields should be used). Is there a cleaner approach than using pattern matching?

```
def foo[T <: MyBaseConfiguration](config: T) = {
  println("do smething")
  println(config.configValue)
}

override def foo[T <: MyBaseConfiguration](config: T) = {
  config match {
    case c: MyOtherConfiguration => {
      println("do smething else")
      println(c.configValue)
      println(c.otherValue)

    }
  }
}

trait MyBaseConfiguration {
  def configValue: String
}

class MyOtherConfiguration extends MyBaseConfiguration {
  val otherValue = 1234

  override def configValue = "abcd"
}
```

## edit

Basicylly, I just want to say * there is a function `f` with a defined return value `TReturn` but be agnostic to input parameters.
Still, I need to be able to use / access them during the execution of `f`.

Comment: The simple answer is that `def foo(x: Any*): TReturn` will allow you to "pass a variable list of parameters and types to a function" but I suspect that is not what you want. I think you need to explain how you want to use this function that you are describing.

Comment: Indeed, inside the function I want to be able to refer to i.e. the configuration values of `otherValue` and `configValue` and still keep type safety.

Comment: You could keep what Tim suggested and then simply do a match / case for the type. Once it's matched, you can access the config values. For example in my project we use specific type of configs (that extend a general config). And then we do this when we want to use the specific type of config: val felixConf = config.asInstanceOf[FelixConfig] . (Although case / match probably would be better, especially if you don't have a specific type you want to extend from)

Comment: Have a look at type evidences. Basically they allow you to tell the compiler "I promise you this value is of this type". Maybe it could help you. They're many questions in SO explaining them, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499663/what-precisely-is-a-scala-evidence-parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will move forward as suggested.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You can just say `def otherFoo[T <: MyOtherConfiguration]` which gives you the type you want. It is hard to help without knowing what you want to do with these functions.

Comment: @Tim I believe this will not work as the interface specifies that there is a function foo ....

Comment: So why is it called `otherFoo` not `override foo`? As I said, I think you need to explain your question more clearly so we can work out what you actually want to do. I'm sure we can help you, but you need to be clear on what it actually is that you want.

Comment: Indeed it is a `override foo`. I changed to code.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking to do is something like this:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo[T <: MyBaseConfiguration](config: T) = {
    println("do smething")
    println(config.configValue)
  }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
  override def foo[T <: MyOtherConfiguration](c: T) = {
    println("do smething else")
    println(c.configValue)
    println(c.otherValue)
  }
}
```

However **this will not work** because it breaks type safety. Consider the following:

```
class MyThirdConfiguration extends MyBaseConfiguration {...}

val foo2: Foo = new Foo2
val cfg: MyBaseConfiguration = new MyThirdConfiguration

foo2.foo(cfg)
```

`foo2` is an instance of `Foo2` but looks like a `Foo`. `cfg` is an instance of `MyThirdConfiguration` but looks like `MyBaseConfiguration`. So `foo2.foo(cfg)` is calling `Foo2.foo` with an object that is not `MyOtherConfiguration` and doesn't have the extra fields, even though the types match.

Note that `Foo2.foo` could be defined to take a **superclass** of `MyBaseConfiguration` because this would not break type safety.

Also note that result types for overloaded functions work the other way round. You can return a subclass of the type returned by the base function but not a superclass because the former is type safe but the latter is not.

Comment: But  `class Foo2 extends Foo {
  override def foo` will not compile (as you mention) so if I remove `extends/override`  the following: `val foo2: Foo = new Foo2` will no longer compile. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I don't think you are missing anything, I was just explaining why what you want to do doesn't work. So, yes, the code doesn't compile because it would be dangerous if it did! It may be possible to do what you want to do but I am still not clear what exactly it is that you want to do.

Comment: Your extended example code is exactly what I want to perform. I  have an interface with various implementations. The interface defines a function which additionally gets some input. However the input (named configuration above) changes per implementation of the interface.